# Outlook API "me/messages" mail id is changing when i move it to another folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When GET request the outlook API "me/messages", its working fine and i can get the data from it.

[image]

When I move this email to another folder, the ID field changes. Could you please advise on which field I should use, ensuring that even when moved to another folder, the ID remains unchanged?

Comment: You can use immutable id's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id which shouldn't change when a message is moved.

Answer (score 1):

That is just how Exchange works - moving a message to a different folder results in a different entry id. Exchange embeds both the message and parent folder ids in `PR_ENTRTID`. As seen in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author):

[image]

If you want something that does not change in a copy or move operation, use [PR_SEARCH_KEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsearchkey-canonical-property) MAPI property. You can use it to search and identify messages, but (unlike Graph id or `PR_ENTRYID` in MAPI), it cannot be used to directly open a message.